# How to make my iterated function calculate more quickly?

Tags: functions

```
Sn[n_] := x /; 0 <= n <= 8
Sn[n_] := 0 /; n > 8

Tn[n_] := 1 /; 0 <= n <= 8
Tn[n_] := 0 /; n > 8

Un[n_] := x /; 0 <= n <= 8
Un[n_] := 0 /; n > 8

Z[n_] := n^2 + n;

an[0] = 1;

an[n_] := 
  an[n] = -1/
    Z[n] Sum[((k)*(k - 1)*Sn[n - k] + (k)*Tn[n - k] + Un[n - k])*
      an[k], {k, 0, n - 1, 1}];
an[500]
```

Some friends say my last code was not clear,I am very sorry.Here I rewrite the code.
This code calcute too slowly,please help me!Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using your definitions and looking at the output of `an[10]`, we see that already here the output is very complicated, containing many nested parentheses. But `an[n]` is a polynomial of degree `n` in `x` so it should only have `n` terms (no zeroth order term here).

Much more importantly for speed, your summand is zero whenever `n-k > 8`. So we can restrict the sum to `Max[n - 8, 0] <= k <= n -1` and replace the values of `Sn, Tn, Un`. That should let us `Expand` each `an` such that we don't accumulate extremely many terms/factors. We get:

```
an[n_] := 
  an[n] = Expand[-1/
      Z[n] Sum[((k)*(k - 1)*x + (k)*1 + x)*an[k], {k, Max[n - 8, 0], 
       n - 1, 1}]];
```

Now

```
AbsoluteTiming[an[500];]
```

gives

> {9.699283, Null}

on my desktop computer.